# Problema if/else en C

Tags: c, condiciones

Es un programa para saber si un numero de 5 cifras es capicuo o no, por ello para contar las cifras uso la r, en el caso de ser 11 seria r=2, ya que tiene dos cifras.

El problema aparece cuando al meter en `if(r=x)`, la `r` me varía y no se cuál es el fallo. La `r` la obtengo de subconjunto, es de las primeras veces que uso subconjuntos, a lo mejor por eso falla.

Aquí el código:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int A(int, int);
int B(int, int, int);
int C(int, int, int);
int D(int, int);
int R(int, int, int);

int main(){
int n, a,b,c,d;
int y,w,e,r,f;
printf("Introduzca un numero:");
scanf("%i",&n);

a=A(n,a);
b=B(n,b,y);
c=C(n,c,w);
d=D(n,d);
r=R(n,e,f);

printf("%i\n",j);
if(r=2) {if(d==c) {printf("Es capicuo \n");}
        else {printf("No es capicuo \n");}}

if(r=3) {if(a==d)printf("Es capicuo \n");
        else printf("No es capicuo 3\n"); }

if(r=4){if(a==d){if(b==c)printf("Es capicuo\n");
                  else printf("No es capicuo\n");}}

if(r=5){if(a==d){if(b==c)printf("Es capicuo\n");
          else printf("No es capicuo\n");}}

system("pause");
return 0;
}


//calcula A

int A(int u, int i){
i=u;
do{i=i/10;
}while(i>=10);
return i;}


//calcula B

int B(int u, int x,int y){
x=u;
do{x=x/10;
}while(x>=100);
y=x;
do{y=y/10;
}while(y>=10);
y=y*10;
x=x-y;
return x;
}


//Calcula C

int C(int u, int q,int w){
q=u;

do{q=q/10;
}while(q>=1000);
w=q;
do{w=w/10;
}while(w>=100);
w=w*10;
q=q-w;
return q;
}

//Calcula D
int D(int u, int o){
o=u/10;
o=o*10;
o=u-o;
return o;
}

//calcula numero cifras
int R(int u,int p, int t){
p=u;
t=0;
do{p=p/10;
   t=t+1;}while(p>=1);
   return t;
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido. Es pésima idea poner caracteres basura en vez de revisar qué más nos puedes contar sobre el problema, como algunos datos de prueba con el resultado esperado del programa (y el resultado actual), cosas así. Las validaciones a las preguntas nuevas están para ayudarte a que te ayuden más rápido. Lo otro: ¿C o C++? (para confirmar)

Comment: Lo siento, me acabo de crear la cuenta y no sabia muy bien como va este foro, pero me lo apunto para la proxima. Sobre mi pregunta ya esta solucionada aun asin gracias por su interes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (r=x)
```

`r=x` es una asignación. Lo que hace es

1. Asignar el valor de x a r
2. Devolver el valor de r (que ahora es x) como el valor de la expresión.
3. Si lo que devuelve es 0, el if lo interpreta como falso; cualquier otra cosa es verdadero.

Usa el **comparador**, ==

```
if (r==x)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, ahora si que me funciona a la perfeccion.